# Unlinking Excel Chart using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, charts, sendkeys, unlink

Hi i have been looking for a solution to unlink my chart (within the same worksheet) from the values.
For this I would usually select the data, go into formulas (F2), press F9 and enter

my series would be turned into numbers.
I automated this as sendkeys, i know there is another option online, but I want the solution as sendkeys.
Basically select Data>F2>F9>Enter. This works fine if i do it manually.

My VBa code looks like this

```
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
Application.SendKeys ("^{s}")
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Select
Application.SendKeys ("{f2}"), True
Application.SendKeys ("{f9}"), True
Application.SendKeys ("{f9}"), True
Application.SendKeys ("~"), True
Application.SendKeys ("^{s}")

ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
Application.SendKeys ("{f2}"), True
Application.SendKeys ("{f9}"), True
Application.SendKeys ("~"), True
```

Yet, one half of the 2nd set of data is still linked.

Thank you for your help in advance - LGR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to convert the `Series.Values` from a *reference* to a `Range`, to the actual underlying values.

```
Sub foo()
Dim cht As Chart
Dim srs As Series

Set cht = ActiveChart

For Each srs In cht.SeriesCollection

    srs.Values = srs.Values

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I have found several other "solutions" online by now, all of them with the same purpose. Yours is by far the most efficient, simple and short solution I have found, brilliantly simple. It seems so easy that I cant think of how others and I haven't thought about this before.

Comment: The only thing which bothers me is that the x-axis labeling is deleted if i delete a line. E.g. Process:5, if deleted turns into "":5. Maybe you do have another solution for me, working with Charts in VBA is new to me.

Comment: @LGR not quite sure what the problem might be but I would suggest asking a new/separate question this way more people will be able to help with it (and of course, if I have time I will try to check it out, too). Try to include screenshots with your explanation as well!  Cheers

Comment: Very simple solution! I hacked around creating a new `Formula`-String from  `Values`, `XValues` and `Name?.

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid using send keys.  Use this instead:

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).LinkFormat.BreakLink
```

Source: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?45829-How-to-break-links-to-excel-chart

Edit: As per comment from David Zemens, this will work for Embedded charts, but not with excel chart objects

Comment: This works for embedded charts, but it doesn't work for a normal Excel ChartObject which resides in the worksheet.

Comment: @DavidZemens Will add a note to the answer